# wordpress logic help ( dropdown ) selcected item

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a very simple code that list's all the custom post types and let's the user choose from them using "for each loop"
 the problem is when giving selected value it's duplicated as it's already there as for each loop list's it there too.. 
 so i don't know how to exclude the user selected item from the drop down menu any ways hope to get some help thanks in advance here is the code ..

```
    <?php // select funeral home  ad's plugin 
$mypostype = get_posts('post_type=funeral_homes');
if($mypostype) : ?>

            <?php  
            $funeral_home_meta = get_post_meta($curpost->ID, '_selected_funeral_homes', true); 
//echo  $funeral_home_meta ;
$the_post_value = $curpost ->ID ;
//echo $the_post_value ;

$adhome_id = $funeral_home_meta;
$queried_post = get_post($adhome_id);
$ad_title = $queried_post->post_title;

?>    

<label for="my_select">Funeral home ad ? </label>
<select id="my_select" name="my_select">
<?php foreach ( $mypostype as $mypost  ) : ?>
<option value="<?php  echo $mypost->ID ;  ?>"><?php echo $mypost->post_title ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $funeral_home_meta ?>" selected><?php echo $ad_title 
//the proplem lays here  ?></option> 
 </select>
</form>
<?php endif ?>
```

as   to set the selected value i had to mention it again so  , it's duplicated is there any alternatives ??? .. thanks again .. basem

Comment: Try: `get_posts('post_type=funeral_homes&exclude='. get_the_ID())`

Comment: Thanks sir for your quick reply the upper code is working perfectly but the problem as you see is when i added  <option value="<?php echo $funeral_home_meta ?>" selected><?php echo $ad_title 
  ?></option> another duplicate of the selected item shows .. so it shows twice one with the loop and one for the selected item .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your foreach loop as following.

```
<?php foreach ( $mypostype as $mypost  ) :
if($mypost->ID==get_the_ID()) // check the it is current post
    continue;
?>
<option value="<?php  echo $mypost->ID ;  ?>"><?php echo $mypost->post_title ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: thanks a million sir worked like charm but had to change the validation rule to ($mypost->ID==$funeral_home_meta) .. thanks again sir .. basem